# Notificaciones Mercadopago que es el merchant order y preference id exactamente

Tags: mercadopago

Estoy haciendo la integracion con mercadopago (checkout basico) y la integracion con la api de las notificaciones.

No tuve problemas en hacerlo, pero nos estan surgiendo muchos problemas por el comportamiento de las notificaciones.

Los usuarios hacen un pedido en la plataforma y eso se paga por MP. El external_reference es el id del pedido.

Cuando hago el checkout, guardo en nuestra base de datos  el preference_id asociado a ese pedido.

Problema: **Nos llegan para un mismo pedido y preference_id, distintos merchat_order_id, la primer notificacion que indica que esta pagado y la segunda que no**. Por que? En el panel de mercadopago no figuran en disputa ni cancelado.

No usamos mercadoenvios.

No tengo mucha informacion mas que esta: https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/api-docs/basic-checkout/merchant-orders/

Cuando creo el preference en el checkout, no tengo el merchat order id segun la documentacion, por lo que tampoco puedo guardarlo de antemano para saber cual es la notificacion que vale
https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/api-docs/basic-checkout/checkout-preferences/

Comment: Te sugiero revisar: [por que no somos soporte de...](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2525/por-qu%C3%A9-no-somos-soporte-al-cliente-de-tu-compa%C3%B1%C3%ADa-favorita). Esta clase de preguntas suelen eliminarse del sitio. revisa los enlaces para conocer la razón. Cualquier pregunta relacionada a programación es bien recibida!